# Spring webapp loading plugins: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web-applications

I am writing a Spring web application, which loads plugin files at runtime. These plugins are classes that implement `IPlugin`. However, when loading the plugin at runtime I get a `ClassNotFoundException`(`IPlugin` cannot be found).

The interface `IPlugin` is located in a package in my web app. In order to build a plugin I exported the interface to a jar file and included it in the plugin's build path.

In my web app, the plugin is loaded using a `URLClassLoader`:

```
URL fileUrl = jar.toURI().toURL();
String jarUrl = "jar: " + fileUrl + "!/";
URL[] urls = new URL[] {new URL(jarUrl)};
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
IPlugin plugin = (IPlugin) Class.forName(clazz, true, loader).newInstance();
```

How do I make the interface available at runtime?

Edit:
It does work if I load the jar containing `IPlugin.class` together with the plugin. But is that really necessary?

Comment: It is added to /lib/ folder or the deployment assembly?

Comment: I assume you are using tomcat, Is this JAR file is existing inside WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: I added the jar containing `IPlugin` to my WEB-INF/lib but the problem remains. Do I need to add the plugin to WEB-INF/lib as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I had to set the parent class loader like this: `new URLClassLoader(URLs, getClass().getClassLoader())`. It is then sufficient to have the `IPlugin` interface present in the webapp, no additional jar is needed in WEB-INF/lib.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use IPlugin without importing on the top

Simply bring the IPlugin.java to your code with the same package name, nothing wrong in this

You can directly use full file path to load a JAR via URLClassLoader

Try the following code

```
URL[] classLoaderUrls = new URL[]{new URL("file:///<your directory path>/<your filename>.jar")};

URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(classLoaderUrls);
Class<?> beanClass = urlClassLoader.loadClass("com.my.MyImplementation");

Constructor<?> constructor = beanClass.getConstructor();
Object beanObj = constructor.newInstance();
```

Try to type cast, if you have IPlugin.java in your import on top this will work

```
IPlugin plugin = (IPlugin)beanObj;
```

Otherwise you need to use Reflection

```
Method method = beanClass.getMethod("myMethod");
method.invoke(beanObj);
```

Comment: I have `IPlugin` with the same package name in my web app, but still I get a `ClassNotFoundException` when calling `urlClassLoader.loadClass("...")`

Comment: you must have **import <the package>.IPlugin** on top and you must be able to compile it